# Memory leak - python - counter - lists in dicts

Tags: list, dictionary

```
    file_dict = {}
    for calli, callj in itertools.product(feats,feats):
        keys = seqd.keys()
        if (not calli in keys) | ((not callj in keys)):
            continue
        else:
            lst = []
            ##### this is the problematic part   !!!!!!!!!
            for jj, ii in itertools.product(seqd[callj], seqd[calli]):
                if (jj - ii) > 0:
                    lst.append(1. / (jj - ii))
                    del jj,ii
            entry = sum(lst)
            del lst
            file_dict[str(calli) + " " + str(callj) + " distance"] = entry
```

I am using the above snippet in some code and iterating over files. I have a memory leak of some sort. If I just comment out those 4 lines which are in the loop I highlighted, my code stays at constant RAM ~100mb. However, when I uncomment this, it goes up to ~8-9GB super fast. Please help!!

Comment: You should try to write a [MCVE] of this, as it is, it's pretty hard for others to reason about although the cartesian products should give you pause. It's also not clear what you're trying to accomplish, what the point of these `del`s is, etc. 'My code is broken, fix it' tends to be a hard question to get help with.

Comment: Note: ``|`` is the bitwise OR operator, not the boolean operator that you want - which is spelled ``or`` in Python.  ``or`` is more efficient, in that it can skip evaluation of the right-hand side if the left side was true (thus making the result unconditionally true).

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I found a solution and am posting it below!

Answer (score 0):

For context, I am replicating the algorithm on page 5 of this paper, generating a system call dependency graph.

Here is the full code fix. It basically involved using a list comprehension within a sum, but without putting brackets around the comprehension. That way items were summed as they were generated instead of first building up the list...

Here is the code:

```
def graph_maker_dict(feats, calls):
# get dictionary of present calls and list of indexes where they appear
seqd = defaultdict(list)
for v, k in enumerate(calls):
    seqd[k].append(v)

# run calculations with list comprehensions
file_dict = {}
for calli, callj in itertools.product(feats,feats):
    keys = seqd.keys()
    if (not calli in keys) or ((not callj in keys)):
        continue
    else:
        entry = sum(1. / (jj - ii) for jj in seqd[callj] for ii in seqd[calli] if (jj - ii) > 0)
        file_dict[calli[:2] + " " + callj[:2] + " distance"[:2]] = entry
return file_dict
```

Comment: That's called a 'generator expression', if you ever need to google it.